# Changing EC2 Instance Type modified EBS root device UUID and made disk read only. How to resolve?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, amazon-ebs

I had a fully working Amazon Linux 2 instance, running on t2.small instance type. I wanted to try changing the instance to a t2.medium type to test. As I have done in the past, I simply shut down the instance, changed the type, and then restarted the instance.

After the restart, apache was down and my sites were un-reachable. I was able to login to the instance and when trying to start apache I discovered that the root drive was now read only which prevented start/etc. Through some troubleshooting I was able to get the drive remounted and thing running as normal, but everytime I restart the instance, it goes back to read-only and I have to perform the same fix each time to get it back to normal. I believe it's an issue with my /etc/fstab root device UUID not matching the current root device UUID. I never changed any of the attached EBS volumes, so I'm not sure how the change occured.

Some relevant info:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="centos rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2"
HOME_URL="https://amazonlinux.com/"
```

To discover the UUID mismatch/fix, I performed the following:

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  50G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0  50G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0  50G  0 disk 
xvdf    202:80   0  50G  0 disk 
└─xvdf1 202:81   0  50G  0 part 

$ sudo blkid
/dev/xvda1: LABEL="/" UUID="2a7884f1-a23b-49a0-8693-ae82c155e5af" TYPE="xfs" PARTLABEL="Linux" PARTUUID="4d1e3134-c9e4-456d-a253-374c91394e99"
/dev/xvdf1: LABEL="/" UUID="a8346192-0f62-444c-9cd0-655ed0d49a8b" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux" PARTUUID="2688b30d-29ef-424f-9196-05ec7e4a0d80"
```

I had read that a possible fix would be to perform the following:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /
mount: /: can't find UUID=-1a7884f1-a23b-49a0-8693-ae82c155e5af.
```

Obviously, that didn't work. So I looked at my /etc/fstab:

```
#
UUID=-1a7884f1-a23b-49a0-8693-ae82c155e5af     /           xfs    defaults,noatime  1   1
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Seeing this mismatch, I tried:

```
sudo mount -o remount nouuid /
```

Which worked, made the root writeable and I was able to get services back up and running.

So, this is how I've come to the belief that it has to do with the mismatch of the UUID in fstab.

My Questions:

1. Should I change the entry in /etc/fstab to match the current UUID: 2a7884f1-a23b-49a0-8693-ae82c155e5af
2. Any idea why this happened and how I can prevent it from happening in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error after I changed the type of EBS.
For anyone who facing the same error, while you are in a situation where the root disk is "read-only" (You cannot use TAB to auto-complete) here is what you should do:

1. Execute `lsblk` to list which device you are using as root disk or data disk
2. Execute `blkid` to obtain the **UUID** of this disk
3. Execute `mount UUID=aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee -o remount,rw /`
   And your root disk should work just fine.

After that, you also need to change the UUID of the disk in `/etc/fstab`.
Also, don't forget to double-check the `/boot/grub2.cfg`, make sure that the kernel parameter has the correct UUID attached. If you upgrade the kernel without the correct UUID in fstab, there could be a misconfigured UUID in grub2.cfg

---

If somehow, you are unable to get in the system, there will be a prompt "unable to find disk /dev/disk/by-uuid/aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee" in the Console Terminal, here is how you solve this.

1. Shutdown the EC2 and unmount the root disk from the AWS web page
2. Initiate a new EC2
3. Mount the root disk to this new EC2 as `/dev/xvdf`
4. Execute `mount /dev/xvdf /mnt` to mount the root disk
5. Execute `lsblk` and `blkid` to obtain the correct UUID
6. Replace the incorrect UUID in `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub2.cfg`
7. Shutdown and unmount the root disk, and re-mount this root disk to where it should belongs.